# capistrano, rails, PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano

I'm trying to run Capistrano for a rails app with Postgres on Ubuntu 14, I ran into a password error during `rake db:migrate`-

```
DEBUG [2823f146] Command: cd /home/ben/apps/mll/releases/20160414014303 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.0.0-p645" RAILS_ENV="production" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate )
DEBUG [2823f146]  rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I tried every solution to similar posts but no luck. For kicks I also tried running just that command in the remote app dir and got the following:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mll"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mll"
```

This is interesting because it's using my database name as my username. See `database.yml` below, so for the hell of it I added a `mll` role, and lo and behold it worked when just running `rake db:migrate`. I tried running Capistrano again though with this new role, and still no luck.

Is it a reasonable guess that the username is not being accessed/stored properly? Any way for me to test that? I manually `ALTER ROLE ben WITH PASSWORD 'mypw';` for both my `ben` and `mll` roles, and nothing.

My database.yml:

```
defaults: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  encoding: utf8

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3_test

production:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: mll
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

\du:

```
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 ben       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB              | {}
 mll       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB              | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

I read changing `md5` to `trust` helped some people, I tried that, but I'm unsure how to restart, all commands I've seen haven't worked for me.

pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "trust" under method for localhost in `pg_hba.conf`. Note that this means all connections from localhost will be able to login as any user, which is probably fine as long as you're using this for development.

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

After changing your `pg_hba.conf` you can restart postgres with `pg_ctl reload`

Comment: I feel like a bonehead, finally got it to restart using SQL `SELECT pg_reload_conf();` and shit, that worked. thanks.

Comment: No prob, we've all been there.

Comment: what about production, any resources/topics I can read up on, on how I can make this safe and not run into this issue?

Comment: This solution will work irrespective of the password. This will trust all connections. So we need to use md5 as a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

**The best practice to resolve the issue is -**

1. Add the below gem in your **Gemfile** under development group and bundle install.

   **gem 'capistrano-postgresql'**
2. Add the below line in **Capfile**

   **require 'capistrano/postgresql'**
3. Add below lines in **config/deploy.rb** or in **config/deploy/*.rb**

   **set :pg_password, ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD']**

   **set :pg_ask_for_password, true**